# Plot triangular grid with cartopy and matplotlib.tri

Tags: matplotlib, triangular, cartopy

I'm trying to plot a triangular grid with cartopy and matplotlib.tri. I use a `matplotlib.tri.Triangulation` object and would like to plot it with `matplotlib.pyplot.triplot`.

When I pass the cartopy projection as a transformation to triplot with `transform=projection`, as I would do for plotting a line, not all triangles are drawn and I get an `IndexError` when trying to save the figure.

On the other hand, when I transform all points in the triangulation manually and call triplot, it works.

In the first example below, all triangles are drawn and the `Line2D` objects do not differ. But trying to save the figure raises an `IndexError`.

In the second example, the resulting `Line2D` objects from triplot with `transform=projection` and from triplot after the manual transformation differ in the result of their transformations applied to their data. So maybe it's a problem of the order of combined transformations.

N.B.: I chose PlateCarree to keep it as simple as possible. I had the same problem with other combinations of axes and data projections.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from cartopy.crs import PlateCarree
from matplotlib.tri import Triangulation

plt.interactive(False)

# NB. plt.triplot returns a list of two Line2D objects in both cases
# the second of which is empty, therefore only the first is returned

def triplot_with_transform(triangulation):
    """
    triangulation: matplotlib.tri.Triangulation

    """
    plt.figure()
    plt.subplot(projection=PlateCarree())
    lines = plt.triplot(triangulation, transform=PlateCarree())
    return plt.gcf(), lines[0]


def transform_before_triplot(triangulation):
    """
    triangulation: matplotlib.tri.Triangulation

    """
    plt.figure()
    plt.subplot(projection=PlateCarree())
    [x_tr, y_tr, _] = PlateCarree().transform_points(PlateCarree(),
                                                     triangulation.x,
                                                     triangulation.y).T
    triangulation_tr = Triangulation(x_tr, y_tr, triangulation.triangles)
    lines = plt.triplot(triangulation_tr)
    return plt.gcf(), lines[0]


def compare_line2d(line1, line2):
    """
    line1, line2 : matplotlib.lines.Line2D

    """
    data1 = line1.get_xydata()
    transform1 = line1.get_transform()
    data2 = line2.get_xydata()
    transform2 = line2.get_transform()
    data1_ma = np.ma.masked_invalid(data1)
    data2_ma = np.ma.masked_invalid(data2)
    data1_tr = transform1.transform(data1)
    data2_tr = transform2.transform(data2)
    data1_tr_ma = np.ma.masked_invalid(data1_tr)
    data2_tr_ma = np.ma.masked_invalid(data2_tr)

    print 'NaNs in line data match ', np.all(data1_ma.mask == data2_ma.mask)
    print 'Line data mismatch', abs(data1_ma-data2_ma).max()

    print 'NaNs in transformed line data match ', np.all(data1_tr_ma.mask ==
                                                         data2_tr_ma.mask)
    print 'Transformed line data mismatch', abs(data1_tr_ma-data2_tr_ma).max()


def try_so_save(fig):
    try:
        fig.savefig('triangulation.pdf')
    except Exception as e:
        print "Exception while saving figure\n", e.__repr__()


# First example, 100 vertices.
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0, 50, 5), np.arange(0, 50, 5))
tri = Triangulation(x.ravel(), y.ravel())
fig1, line1 = triplot_with_transform(tri)
fig2, line2 = transform_before_triplot(tri)

# Second example, 2500 vertices.
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0, 50), np.arange(0, 50))
tri = Triangulation(x.ravel(), y.ravel())
fig3, line3 = triplot_with_transform(tri)
fig4, line4 = transform_before_triplot(tri)

# Compare Line2D objects; since we transform from PlateCarree to
# PlateCarree, the lines should be (almost) equal.
print "Line2D objects from first example"
compare_line2d(line1, line2)
print "Line2D objects from second example"
compare_line2d(line3, line4)

# Try to save the figures.
print "Save fig1 from first example."
try_so_save(fig1)
print "Save fig3 from second example."
try_so_save(fig3) 

# failing plt.savefig command to produce full traceback
fig1.savefig('triangulation.pdf')
```

The output is

```
Line2D objects from first example
NaNs in line data match  True
Line data mismatch 3.5527136788e-15
NaNs in transformed line data match  True
Transformed line data mismatch 0.0
Line2D objects from second example
NaNs in line data match  True
Line data mismatch 7.1054273576e-15
NaNs in transformed line data match  True
Transformed line data mismatch 3545.955
Save fig1 from first example.
Exception while saving figure
IndexError('Out of bounds on buffer access (axis 0)',)
Save fig3 from second example.
Exception while saving figure
IndexError('Out of bounds on buffer access (axis 0)',)
```

When trying to save any of the figures created with `transform=projection`, `cartopy._crs.CRS.transform_points` raises the `IndexError`.

Is this a problem of cartopy or matplotlib.tri? And is there a way to avoid the manual transformation and pass a `transform` argument to triplot?

Edit:

After pp-mo's answer, I found that adding a format string with a marker, like `'o-'`, to the triplot command makes it work. Just changing the color (`'g-`) does not help, though.

Edit 2:

Added `fig1.savefig` in the example code to produce full traceback.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this, and there doesn't seem to be a fundamental problem with the mechanics.
Here is a simple working example...

```
"""
Example shamelessly poached from http://matplotlib.org/mpl_examples/pylab_examples/triplot_demo.py

We just add a mapping transform to the second figure there...

"""
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.tri as tri
import numpy as np
import math

import cartopy.crs as ccrs

# Some points defining a triangulation over (roughly) Britain.
xy = np.asarray([
    [-0.101, 0.872], [-0.080, 0.883], [-0.069, 0.888], [-0.054, 0.890],
    [-0.045, 0.897], [-0.057, 0.895], [-0.073, 0.900], [-0.087, 0.898],
    [-0.090, 0.904], [-0.069, 0.907], [-0.069, 0.921], [-0.080, 0.919],
    [-0.073, 0.928], [-0.052, 0.930], [-0.048, 0.942], [-0.062, 0.949],
    [-0.054, 0.958], [-0.069, 0.954], [-0.087, 0.952], [-0.087, 0.959],
    [-0.080, 0.966], [-0.085, 0.973], [-0.087, 0.965], [-0.097, 0.965],
    [-0.097, 0.975], [-0.092, 0.984], [-0.101, 0.980], [-0.108, 0.980],
    [-0.104, 0.987], [-0.102, 0.993], [-0.115, 1.001], [-0.099, 0.996],
    [-0.101, 1.007], [-0.090, 1.010], [-0.087, 1.021], [-0.069, 1.021],
    [-0.052, 1.022], [-0.052, 1.017], [-0.069, 1.010], [-0.064, 1.005],
    [-0.048, 1.005], [-0.031, 1.005], [-0.031, 0.996], [-0.040, 0.987],
    [-0.045, 0.980], [-0.052, 0.975], [-0.040, 0.973], [-0.026, 0.968],
    [-0.020, 0.954], [-0.006, 0.947], [ 0.003, 0.935], [ 0.006, 0.926],
    [ 0.005, 0.921], [ 0.022, 0.923], [ 0.033, 0.912], [ 0.029, 0.905],
    [ 0.017, 0.900], [ 0.012, 0.895], [ 0.027, 0.893], [ 0.019, 0.886],
    [ 0.001, 0.883], [-0.012, 0.884], [-0.029, 0.883], [-0.038, 0.879],
    [-0.057, 0.881], [-0.062, 0.876], [-0.078, 0.876], [-0.087, 0.872],
    [-0.030, 0.907], [-0.007, 0.905], [-0.057, 0.916], [-0.025, 0.933],
    [-0.077, 0.990], [-0.059, 0.993]])
# Make lats + lons
x = xy[:, 0]*180/3.14159
y = xy[:, 1]*180/3.14159

# A selected triangulation of the points.
triangles = np.asarray([
    [67, 66,  1], [65,  2, 66], [ 1, 66,  2], [64,  2, 65], [63,  3, 64],
    [60, 59, 57], [ 2, 64,  3], [ 3, 63,  4], [ 0, 67,  1], [62,  4, 63],
    [57, 59, 56], [59, 58, 56], [61, 60, 69], [57, 69, 60], [ 4, 62, 68],
    [ 6,  5,  9], [61, 68, 62], [69, 68, 61], [ 9,  5, 70], [ 6,  8,  7],
    [ 4, 70,  5], [ 8,  6,  9], [56, 69, 57], [69, 56, 52], [70, 10,  9],
    [54, 53, 55], [56, 55, 53], [68, 70,  4], [52, 56, 53], [11, 10, 12],
    [69, 71, 68], [68, 13, 70], [10, 70, 13], [51, 50, 52], [13, 68, 71],
    [52, 71, 69], [12, 10, 13], [71, 52, 50], [71, 14, 13], [50, 49, 71],
    [49, 48, 71], [14, 16, 15], [14, 71, 48], [17, 19, 18], [17, 20, 19],
    [48, 16, 14], [48, 47, 16], [47, 46, 16], [16, 46, 45], [23, 22, 24],
    [21, 24, 22], [17, 16, 45], [20, 17, 45], [21, 25, 24], [27, 26, 28],
    [20, 72, 21], [25, 21, 72], [45, 72, 20], [25, 28, 26], [44, 73, 45],
    [72, 45, 73], [28, 25, 29], [29, 25, 31], [43, 73, 44], [73, 43, 40],
    [72, 73, 39], [72, 31, 25], [42, 40, 43], [31, 30, 29], [39, 73, 40],
    [42, 41, 40], [72, 33, 31], [32, 31, 33], [39, 38, 72], [33, 72, 38],
    [33, 38, 34], [37, 35, 38], [34, 38, 35], [35, 37, 36]])

# Make a triangulation object
my_tris = tri.Triangulation(x, y, triangles)

# Plot over an OSGB map with a coastline.
crs_pc = ccrs.PlateCarree()
crs_uk = ccrs.OSGB()
plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection=crs_uk)
ax.coastlines(color='red', linewidth=1.5)
plt.triplot(my_tris,
            'go-',
            transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

*So...*
I'm just guessing that your problem could be that your actual triangulation (which points are connected in triangles) is no longer appropriate when the points have been passed through the transform.
The most obvious reason would be that the triangles cross a "seam" in the projection. For example, you might have longitudes from -30 to +30, but want to plot on a map that runs from 0 to 360deg.

*Is that a possible cause ?*

Comment: No, I don't think that's a possible cause, in particular since I'm not crossing anything with the example data above. But I tried your example and it worked. Then I took out the format string `'go-'` in the plot command and ran into the same error. Vice versa, if I add `'go-'` or just `'o-'` to my example, it runs through and saves without errors. And the difference in the transformed line data is 0 in both cases. Funny thing...

Comment: If I completely remove that from the above example code, it still works for me.  Does it not for you ?  Are you using all keyword names to be sure it isn't an argument order problem ?

According to the documentation, the plot string controls are the same as for plot() :  The 'g' means green, the 'o' means circle markers, the '-' means solid linestyle.
So it seems maybe a bit odd for it to make a key difference.

Comment: Sorry for name change, I just edited my profile.  
On second thoughts, reading your output text -- though you don't give code behind it, it does mention NaNs, so I'm wondering if there could be a Cartopy-specific problem due to that.  
Can you post a complete working example (that is, one that fails !)

Comment: Have you tried saving the figure? The example code above works for me, too. But trying to `plt.savefig` raises the `IndexError` in my case (as in the first example in the original question).

Comment: The output text is produced by `compare_line2d`, defined in the example code above. And as far as I understand, the NaNs aren't cartopy-specific. They also appear when triplotting in an ordinary matplotlib axes.

Comment: Unfortunately I think I'm at the end of what I can contribute here :  
I'm not able to reproduce this - I tried your suggestions and it still all "just works" for me.  
If it helps, I have the following module versions installed : matplotlib=1.3.1 ; cartopy=0.13.0 ; numpy=1.8.2

Comment: Thanks for the effort and the differing versions are a starting point because I am using matplotlib version 1.4.3. And I can now confirm that your example works and `plt.savefig` works with matplotlib=1.3.1. When I downgraded matplotlib with conda to test this, a few other packages changed, mainly numpy 1.9.2->1.8.2. Moreover, my example won't run in matplotlib 1.3.1 because it seems plt.triplot returns None, but I can confirm that it's possible to save the figures in both cases with matplotlib=1.3.1